# How do I map my row key in source to row key in sink? Not working as expected

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-data-factory

I am using Azure Data Factory to transform a blob, then I am trying to copy it in Azure Table Storage. I am using the copy activity. The pipeline consists of the data flow, then the copy activity.

Everything is working well except for mapping my rowkey. I used the transform activity to generate a rowkey based on product SKUs. When I go to sink and select "use source column", it shows a "select option" under "row key column" but my only option is "Add dynamic content" and I don't get any column options.

My rowkey in the source is mapped via the mapping function, but it appears that without specifying dynamic content it's being overridden with a unique identifier by default. Since these are product SKUs and I want to merge data, I absolutely need my own rowkeys.

I am new to ADF, I've tried referencing my rowkey using dynamic content but it only generates not found errors. I'm not sure if I'm referencing the source right when writing an expression.

I've contacted Azure support and I'm awaiting a response, but we'll see.

```
{
    "name": "BlobTransformsToTable",  
    "properties": {  
        "activities": [  
            {
                "name": "TransformThenCopyToTable",  
                "type": "Copy",  
                "dependsOn": [  
                    {  
                        "activity": "MyVendorCatalog",  
                        "dependencyConditions": [  
                            "Succeeded"  
                        ]  
                    }  
                ],  
                "policy": {  
                    "timeout": "7.00:00:00",  
                    "retry": 0,  
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,  
                    "secureOutput": false,  
                    "secureInput": false  
                },  
                "typeProperties": {  
                    "source": {  
                        "type": "DelimitedTextSource",  
                        "storeSettings": {  
                            "type": "AzureBlobStorageReadSetting",  
                            "wildcardFileName": "*.*"  
                        },  
                        "formatSettings": {  
                            "type": "DelimitedTextReadSetting"  
                        }  
                    },  
                    "sink": {  
                        "type": "AzureTableSink",  
                        "azureTableInsertType": "merge",  
                        "azureTableDefaultPartitionKeyValue": "CatalogItem",  
                        "writeBatchSize": 10000  
                    },  
                    "enableStaging": false,  
                    "translator": {  
                        "type": "TabularTranslator",  
                        "mappings": [  
                            {  
                                "source": {  
                                    "name": "PartitionKey",  
                                    "type": "String"  
                                },
                                "sink": {  
                                    "name": "PartitionKey"  
                                }  
                            },  
                            {  
                                "source": {  
                                    "name": "RowKey",  
                                    "type": "String"  
                                },  
                                "sink": {  
                                    "name": "RowKey"  
                                }  
                            },
```

[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1wHi.png)
[Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pv6nJ.png)

I am expecting it to map rowkey in source to rowkey in sink. It's still generating unique values. I'm open to working around the problem by using dynamic content, but I'm not sure how to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue and was able to resolve as follows.

Edit your pipeline and navigate to the [Sink] Tab

- [Row Key value selection] should be specified as "Use Sink Column"
- [Row Key column] should be specified as "RowKey" when the [Add Dynamic Content Selection] screen is opened

Then on the mapping screen you can map the Source Field to the "RowKey" column and it will be respected

[Row Key Column screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WE3X2.png)